# Flutter - How to enable control-flow-collection?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying use control-flow-collections in Flutter(Google's UI toolkit) to enable the use of inline `for` loop, i.e:

```
for (int i = 0; i < globals.currentScaleList.scales.length; i++)
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    globals.currentScaleList.scales[i].scaleType.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ], itemExtent: 23.0, onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {}),
```

I have seen the other questions on the topics in SO and followed all of the instructions that seem to work for others.

1. I am running Flutter 1.15.4-pre.248 on the Master channel and Dart 2.8.0

```
Flutter 1.15.4-pre.248 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 686d163420 (2 hours ago) • 2020-03-02 16:25:22 -0500
Engine • revision 5e474ee860
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.10.0 fbe9f6115d)
```

2. I have created a analysis_options.yaml file in my root app folder and added the following:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - control-flow-collections
```

3. I have also updated the min version of Dart in my pubspec.yaml, i.e.:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.0 <3.0.0"
```

However, I still get the error against my 'for' loop stating:

"This requires the 'control-flow-collections' experiment to be enabled.
Try enabling this experiment by adding it to the command line when compiling and running."

When I do enable the 3 lines in my analysis_options.yaml file, I get the warning:

"The option 'control-flow-collection' isn't supported by 'enable-experiment'."

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Inline loops in collection literals were officially introduced in Dart 2.3 (Flutter 1.5) and aren't experimental anymore, so you shouldn't need to configure anything. If you are having issues with them, there might be a bug in the latest master build. Switch to one of the other channels and see if the issue remains.

Comment: Thanks. It seemed that a ````flutter clean```` followed by a restart of VSCode and removal of the analysis_options.yaml file did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing this issue and have tried creating the analysis_options.yaml, I did what Paul Toal said on the last comment.

- Remove analysis_options.yaml (if created)
- Run **flutter clean** command
- Restart VSCode

This one worked for me, using the following.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.2 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the `moor_database.g.dart`, the Moor generated file. I got it fixed by:

1- Upgrading the sdk constraints with the following

```
environment:
    sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"
```

2- On `DartAnalysis` in the Android Studio, click on `Restart Dart Analysis Server`, the first icon button on top left of the DartAnalysis window.

Weird, but worked.